# Python macros are currently disabled

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I made a plugin and when I launch it it gives me this problem.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to include information about your platform and release, and to include the error message as text, since images are not legible on all devices, and are not searchable either.

Answer (score 5):

Try enabling macros from the menubar:

```
Settings > Options > General
```

[image: Enable macros]

Personally I set it to `Always` but depends on your use-case.